# Exclude the ones that are related in DataMapper (CodeIgniter)?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

This gets all the related items:

```
$item->get_by_related($user);
```

However, how to get only the ones that aren't related?

I imagine this can be done by using `where`, but what about many-to-many relationships?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this by little Googling. Really weird it's under Troubleshooting, as it's more of a feature rather than an error.

http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/troubleshooting.html#Relationships.NotRelated

Comment: +1: I've been using Datamapper for over a year now and didn't know this feature existed because it's buried under the troubleshooting page. Learned something new so I fav'd too. Cheers.